# Do I need to report a subcontractor injury?

Tags: insurance, homeownership

I have a house that I purchased that has been under a major renovation for 7 months. We hired a general contractor to oversee the project.

Today when I got to the house to check in on things, one of the subcontractors (the kitchen installer) said to me: “Did you hear what happened on Thursday?” Not knowing what he meant, I said “No, what happened?”

He said he had cut his hand on a saw, and then made a slightly strange comment along the lines of “don’t worry, I won’t sue you”.

My question is, should I do anything about this? We have builders risk insurance on the property so we are supposed to be covered for injuries and things like this. Most likely nothing will come of it, but am I supposed to report it to insurance now just in case this guy does decide to sue us years from now?

Or is the general contractor the one who needs to know about it since he is technically the one employing them?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this subcontractor an independent contractor, or an employee of a larger company?

Comment: The subcontractor is a company. I do not know the employment status of the individual to that subcontractor. He may be an independent contractor or he may be an employee. I have no idea how they are structured.